# ActivityNotFoundException unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-activity

I am getting this error in my one activity and it is making no sense because I can go to the `Calendar` activity from another activity so I know i declared it correctly in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".Calendar" android:label="Calendar"/>
```

Intent is in a Dialog selection

```
Intent ok = new Intent(Events.this,Calendar.class);
ok.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(ok); //ActivityNotFoundException
finish();
```

I can from activity `A` to the `Calendar` activity just fine then the `Calendar` activity has access to my `Events` activity but I cant go from my `Events` to the `Calendar` activity??

Ideas as to why this is?

EDIT: Update with error

```
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app.notifyme/java.util.Calendar}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at com.app.notifyme.Events$12.onClick(Events.java:318)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1849)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-24 12:53:46.951: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the complete error ? there is probably the qualified name of the activity, which would allow use to verify cristian hypothesis

Comment: updated with full logcat error

Comment: which confirms that you are indeed importing java.util.Calendar instead of com.app.notifyme.Calendar. Replace the first one by the other, and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the correct package. I guess you are importing something like `java.util.Calendar` in your `Events` class.

If, for some reason, you need both `Calendar` classes (the one you wrote and the `java.util` one), you must put the complete path... for instance:

```
Intent ok = new Intent(Events.this, your.pkg.example.Calendar.class);
```

Comment: yes I do have the `java.util.Calendar` package imported in my events class, so what do you mean by import the correct package?

Comment: Replace `import java.util.Calendar;` with `import your.package.Calendar;`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `finish()` the system actually removes the activity from the stack.

This disallows you from going back to that activity.

I suggest you carefully read the [Activity Lifecycle Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

It should help you figure out your problem. :)

EDIT:

You should also not need that flag.  Just start the activity, the system will take care of the rest.

You also do not have access to one activity from another activity.  Each activity is a standalone unit that should not attempt to access other activities.

If you need to pass data between activities, use a static class/variable in a seperate class, or pass it using `Intent.putExtra()`.

Comment: if you look closely, you'll find that the issue is not coming back from Calendar, but to actually get there in the first place. Also, finishing an activity removes it from the stack, meaning that back will take you to the previous one or close the app if there is none.

Comment: I think the OP has an incorrect understanding of what an activity is supposed to be.  You shouldn't try to access one activity from another activity.  I think Cristian's solution is likely correct.  Silly bugs are quite often the toughest to see.

Comment: I understand what an activity does and when I say access I mean I get the that activity from there